# How do I revert input values back to default values onClick in React?

Tags: reactjs, datatable, react-hooks, jsx

I have a data table built in react hooks. On each row I'm allowing the user to edit the values and enter what I'm calling edit mode seen below:

```
enter const TableRow = (props: any) => {
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});
const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false)

const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputs(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
}

const onStartEdit = ()  => setEditMode(true)

const onEditCommit = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    // console.log('on edit inputs: ', inputs)
    // props.updateRow(inputs, props.id)
}
const onCancelEditMode = () =>  setEditMode(false)

return (
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input
                disabled={!editMode}
                name="merchant"
                placeholder="Merchant Name"
                type="text"
                onChange={handleChange}
                defaultValue={props.row.merchant}
            />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input
                disabled={!editMode}
                name="item"
                placeholder="Item"
                type="text"
                onChange={handleChange}
                defaultValue={props.row.item}
            />
        </td>
        <td>
            {props.row.amtCrypto}
        </td>
        <td>
            <input
                disabled={!editMode}
                name="currency"
                placeholder="Currency"
                type="text"
                onChange={handleChange}
                defaultValue={props.row.currency}
            />
        </td>
        <td>
            {props.row.cryptoPrice}
        </td>
        <td>
            <input
                disabled={!editMode}
                name="amount"
                placeholder="Amount(USD)"
                type="text"
                onChange={handleChange}
                defaultValue={props.row.amount}
            />
        </td>
        <td>
            {!editMode &&
                <div>
                    <button
                        onClick={onStartEdit}
                    >
                        Edit
                    </button>
                    <button
                        onClick={onDeleteRow}
                    >
                        Delete Row
                    </button>
                </div>
            }
            {editMode && 
            <div>
                 <button
                        onClick={onEditCommit}
                    >
                        Complete
                    </button>
                    <button
                        onClick={onCancelEditMode}
                    >
                        Cancel
                    </button>
            </div>}
        </td>
    </tr>

)
```

}

So basically on `startEditMode` I am making the fields editable and on cancelEditMode I'd like to lock the fields and revert them back to the default values. How would I implement this?

Comment: When editing starts - you need to store(lock) all the previous values in another variable. When you need to reset/cancel the edit - you need to take current values that a user has edited, and replace them with the previous values.

Answer (score 1):

First you can put the initial values received from props in the inputs state

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({merchant: props.row.merchant, ...});
```

You should use the value of the inputs state as single source of truth.

```
 <input
            disabled={!editMode}
            name="merchant"
            placeholder="Merchant Name"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={inputs.merchant}
        />
```

When the onCancelEditMode function gets called you can set the input state with the initial values from props

```
const onCancelEditMode = () =>  {
    setEditMode(false)
    setInput({merchant: props.row.merchant, ...})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. However, appears this isn't going to work given my handleChange method is updating the state once the user types. Therefore when I cancel edit mode, its reverting back to whatever the user just typed.

Comment: Assuming the props.row.merchant doesn't change between the user enters 'edit mode' and clicking on 'cancel edit mode' or the TableRow component isn't being unmounted you should be able to setInput() in onCancelEditMode with the values from props, since they didn't change. Otherwise you can use another state to store the initial values when this component mounts e.g.

const [initialInputValues, setInitialInputValues] = useState({merchant: props.row.merchant, ... }). and in on onCancelEditMode setInput({...initialInputValues}). Hope this makes sense